# For loop in python is ignoring the if statement

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and I can't see why my for loop is ignoring the if statement and saying every number is a prime number. My code is as such.

```
def prime_number(number):
    sqrt_prime = math.sqrt(number)
    for x in (2,sqrt_prime-1):
        if isinstance((number/x), int) and x <= sqrt_prime-1:
            con_num = str(number)
            print(con_num,end=' ');print('is not a prime number.')
            break
    else:
        con_num = str(number)
        print(con_num,end=' ');print('is a prime number.')
```

It could probably be a lot more streamlined, just want to know why it isn't either outputting true for the isinstance or that x is smaller or equal to the sqrt of the number - 1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check type in `isinstance` it may be float is you're using python3

Comment: `number/x` will always be a float in python3, so your condition will not be satisfied(The same opinion as @neilharia7)

Comment: I wonder if we can reduce the range of `(2, sqrt_prime-1)` to half.

Comment: You might consider checking a potential factor like this: `if number % x == 0` instead of using `/` though personally I would be cautious about `0` vs `0.0` and getting incorrect answers from rounding.  You might also try `if number / x == number // x:`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is python 3.x then it makes sense why it ignores it.

`number/x` will always return a float and not an integer. Thus, `isinstance((number/x), int)` is always False.

Comment: The else statement is attached to the for loop, to be executed if the loop does not break. So it is properly indented.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is
`isinstance((number/x), int)`.

The type is always `float` if you check them by

```
print(type(number/x))
```

Correction:
Change it from

```
        if isinstance((number/x), int) and x <= sqrt_prime-1:
```

to

```
        if number % x == 0 and x <= sqrt_prime-1:
```

Another problem is the coding:

```
def prime_number(number):
    sqrt_prime = math.sqrt(number)
    flg = 0
    for x in (2,sqrt_prime-1):
        if number % x == 0 and x <= sqrt_prime-1:
            con_num = str(number)
            print(con_num,end=' ');print('is not a prime number.')
            flg = 1
            break
    if flg==0:
            con_num = str(number)
            print(con_num,end=' ');print('is a prime number.')
```

I am not sure if you have finished the code, seems like this is algorithm is not running rightly.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the float issue. I also realised I forgot to make it range(2,int(sqrt_prime)-1), so it was only dividing by 2 and then moving on, rather than going up all the values from 2 to the sqrt -1

Comment: `if not number % x and x < sqrt_prime`, `print(number, 'is not a prime number.')` Check [this](https://tio.run/##ZY5NCoMwEIX3PcXbFBWs0HZX6Fkk0gmGNhObRLCnT02i2OLbDLyfjxk@vjd8DeFBEoNVmloedUe2zKe6HTDLva1vU4w7tPB9E521kyrSWExQjPJS//ZPOC@QKCXBxiMPccS0RVHzhFdsjUK51Bb5s2XVFNXfprMknsmhl6ONt2ftOCF8AQ)